# How do I get data from the Route and show it in a html page?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I am trying get a value from the URL for example : websitename.com/dash/namehere

I have route :

```
Route::get('/dash/{id}', 'DashController@index' , function($id) {

    return 'dash'.$id;
});
```

Then I have a section on the page I am trying to display as a title. I am currently using this:

```
@if (\Request::is('dash/1'))  
<div class="pagetitle">[clientname]</div>
@endif
```

This works but I am thinking there is a better way to approach this. I am very new to this.
I want to get the id from the url / site.com/dash/ {id} and use it in the HTML page as a Title header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{{ request()->route('id') }}` in your blade to get the "id" parameter from the dash route.